# How to groupby in pandas and add values from another column and count them

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame like that, I want somehow to groupby the user_search column, count how many of each prediction in the predicted column, add the predicted coin and the numeric value.

| u_search | predicted |
| --- | --- |
| bitcoin | litecoin |
| polkadot | burgerswap |
| cardano | pancake swap |
| bitcoin | litecoin |
| bitcoin | ethereum |

I want to create a dataframe like this

| u_search | predicted |
| --- | --- |
| bitcoin | litecoin 2, ethereum 1 |
| polkadot | burgerswap 1 |
| cardano | pancake swap 1 |

```
user_data = pd.read_csv('static/user_searched_coins_df.csv')
user_data=user_data.groupby(['user searched coin']).....
```

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try out, using [`pd.GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-apply) + [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts)

```
df.groupby('u_search', as_index=False)['predicted'].apply(
    lambda x: ", ".join(f"{k} {v}" for k, v in x.value_counts().items())
)
```

---

```
Out[*]: 

   u_search               predicted
0   bitcoin  litecoin 2, ethereum 1
1   cardano           pancakeswap 1
2  polkadot            burgerswap 1
```

Comment: it works, however it returns a series and I am struggling to output to html with .to_html, any solution?

Comment: @EmiliaDelizia, you might be missing ``as_index=False`` argument for groupby try adding that.

Comment: I used your code as is, it includes as_index

Comment: when I run in google colab it works like making a 2 columns however when I run in Flask it generated a series and if I turn into a dataframe it has only one column of data. The second column where the data is aggregated

Comment: I managed to solve it by setting as_index=False